# Where will I spend eternity

Tags: space, physics, hard-science, chemistry

I walked past a church today, and it had a poster outside saying 'Where will you spend eternity' Which got me thinking

Ignoring what my immortal soul might get up to, where will my body spend eternity. As in what is the timeline. i.e. for a few years I'll turn into wormfood, re-enter the carbon cycle perhaps  but what does my eternity look like

(I wasn't sure whether to ask this here, on physics, chemistry, or space! so I started here - actually all sites could have interesting answers!)

To answer comments (and the on hold!) I actually meant the question in an atoms and molecules kind of way, as in the stuff they put in the ground one day (Or burn, for an alternative answer)

The immortal soul part would be the philosophy question, I'm not overly concerned on that one.

And the inclusion of space is that one day the sun will die etc...

Comment: Don't worry, in a few thousand years you'll get the latest model, with slightly improved appearance and no flaws! Just wait for the fiery doomsday!

Comment: Can you narrow the focus a bit?  Are you looking for a scientific answer, a religious answer, it seems like you want a science answer but I want to make sure, and I don't get the inclusion of space so please explain that as well.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking as well.

Comment: If you intend this in the way I think, as in, what will happen to your body once it is buried in the ground, I think this is off-topic. After all, it's simply a science question. Not at all about building world's.

Comment: This should be moved to http://philosophy.stackexchange.com as this is more of a philosophical question than a world building question and I couldn't find a stackexchange specifically for religion.

Comment: You will find [this](http://www.amazon.com/Atom-Single-Oxygen-Journey-Beyond/dp/0316183091) interesting.

Answer (score 1):

**Possibly, where you're at now, through eternal recurrence.**

The Poincaré recurrence theorem states that certain systems will, given sufficient time, return to an initial state. This could mean that you have asked this question on WorldBuilding.SE an infinite amount of times in the past and will continue to do so an infinite amount of times in the future.

In [Don Page's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9411193.pdf) *Information Loss In Black Holes And/Or Conscious Beings* he describes the recurrence time for a volume of our own universe as follows:

> For a black hole containing the mass within the presently visible region of our universe, it should be of the order of 
>   $ 10^{10^{10^{10^{2.8}}}}$ Planck time, millenia, or whatever.<sup>1</sup>

After this time has elapsed, our universe should restart, and given enough time, all the phenomena and arrangements of matter that led to your consciousness will repeat, and you will ask, "Where will I spend eternity?" and I will give you the answer here:

[Where will you spend eternity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/37422/15401)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>"Whatever" is used here because the timescales required for these phenomena to occur are ungodly massive, far bigger than Googol or even a Googolplex and render the differences between Planck times and yottaseconds meaningless.</sub>

Comment: Does that mean someone's going to hit me with the duplicate hammer? P.S. Nice answer

Comment: That doesn't consider eternal expansion. It is not in thermodynamic equilibrium and the paers are carried away from each other faster than light, so it can't repeat due to thermodynamic statistics.

Comment: I believe the paper does address eternal expansion: He also approximates Linde-type inflationary universes, and this paper expands on that: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208013

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to provide an optimistic answer, assuming that your bits re-enter the carbon cycle and spend the next several hundred years circulating through the life of this little blue planet.

Long before that becomes boring, you will find yourself in one or more colonist's belly, travelling out to the stars.

From there, it is a game of catch me if you can; with each new home-world hosting you for a time, until its primary star approaches collapse.  Then it's off to the stars again, over and over, with worn-out star novae in your wake.

But that game will play out over billions, if not trillions of years.

...and during all that time, the speed of our conquest of science will be ever increasing...

Unimaginable as it may seem, I believe that if it is a race between the human mind and the oncoming heat death of the universe, then the human mind is the odds-on favorite.  Long before everything ends, we will find a way around that minor inconvenience.

Therefore you will go on forever!